# php dynamic associative array displaying wrong result from mysql database

Tags: php, arrays, json, dynamic, associative

**I have two tables "feetypes" and "feedetails" as below**

```
mysql> select * from feetypes;
+------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
| iFeeTypeId | vFeeColumnName | vColumnHeader | iPriority | eDisplay |
+------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|          1 | iBatchYear     | Year          |         5 | 0        |
|          2 | dTutionFee     | Tution Fee    |         4 | 0        |
|          3 | dCautionMoney  | Caution Money |         1 | 0        |
|          4 | dOtherFee      | Other Fee     |         3 | 0        |
|          5 | dMyNewFee      | My New Fee    |         2 | 0        |
+------------+----------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select * from feedetails;
+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| iFeeDetailsId | iSiteConId | iCourseId | iBatchYear | dTutionFee | dCautionMoney | dOtherFee | dMyNewFee | eDeleted | dCreatedDate        | dUpdatedDate        |
+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|             1 |          1 |         1 |       2021 |    1000.00 |       2000.00 |   3000.00 |      0.00 | 0        | 2021-02-18 03:49:18 | 2021-02-18 03:49:18 |
|             2 |          1 |         1 |       2022 |    2000.00 |       2000.00 |   2000.00 |   2000.00 | 0        | 2021-02-18 03:49:18 | 2021-02-18 03:49:18 |
+---------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, I am checking 'feetypes' tables vFeeColumnName attribute with 'feedetails' tables attributes (like dTutionFee,dCautionMoney , dOtherFee, dMyNewFee etc ) and if match is found then it should be process and finally i want to create an array but i am getting wrong array result...

I want result like this:

```
array(size=2)
  0 =>
    array(size=5)
        'dCautionMoney' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
        'dMyNewFee' => string '0.00' (length=4)
        'dOtherFee' => string '3000.00' (length=7)
        'dTutionFee' => string '1000.00' (length=7)
        'iBatchYear' => string '2021' (length=4)
 1 => 
    array(size=5)
        'dCautionMoney' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
        'dMyNewFee' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
        'dOtherFee' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
        'dTutionFee' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
        'iBatchYear' => string '2022' (length=4)
```

but i am getting result like this :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'dCautionMoney' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
      'dMyNewFee' => string '0.00' (length=4)
      'dOtherFee' => string '3000.00' (length=7)
      'dTutionFee' => string '1000.00' (length=7)
      'iBatchYear' => string '2021' (length=4)
      
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'dCautionMoney' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
      'dMyNewFee' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
      'dOtherFee' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
      'dTutionFee' => string '2000.00' (length=7)
      'iBatchYear' => string '2022' (length=4)
      
      1 => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

my code is :

```
//get various fee types start
$queryFeeTypes = "SELECT * FROM feetypes WHERE eDisplay = '0' ORDER BY iPriority ";
$exeFeeTypes =  $pdo->query($queryFeeTypes);
$resultFeeTypes = $exeFeeTypes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//get various fee types end


//get various column  name start
$queryDesFeeDetails = "DESCRIBE feedetails";
$exeDescFeeDetails = $pdo->query($queryDesFeeDetails);
$resultDescFeeDetails = $exeDescFeeDetails->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//get various column  name end


//get fee details start
$queryFeeDetails = "SELECT * FROM  feedetails WHERE eDeleted = '0'";
$exeFeeDetails =  $pdo->query($queryFeeDetails);
$resultFeeDetails = $exeFeeDetails->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//get fee details end 

$data = array();

foreach($resultFeeDetails as $newData) {
    $newArrayData[] = array();
    foreach($resultFeeTypes as $row){
        foreach($resultDescFeeDetails as $rowNew){
            $header =  $rowNew['Field'];
            if($row['vFeeColumnName'] == $rowNew['Field']){
                $newArrayData = array_push_assoc($newArrayData, $header, $newData[$header]);
            }
        }
    }    
array_push($data, $newArrayData);

}

function array_push_assoc($array, $key, $value){
    $array[$key] = $value;
    return $array;
 }

var_dump($data);
?>
```

Comment: Could you please try like this (use code of given link):https://3v4l.org/B9VQt

Comment: $newArrayData[] = array(); you are adding a new array to an array. The array declaration does not need [].  Change your code to $newArrayData = array();

Comment: @Anurat Chapanond Your solution is working. Thanks a lot...